# Backup MS SQL Database with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database-backups, pyodbc

I am trying to backup my database with pyodbc.

The following SQL code has been tested and worked well directly in SQL Server Management Studio

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(MyDB_v0_log, 100)
GO

BACKUP DATABASE comparables
TO  DISK = N'D:\MSSQL\BACKUP\MyDB_v0_noFSD.bak' WITH NOFORMAT
,   INIT
,   NAME = N'backup_MyDB_v0_noFSD.bak', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD
,   STATS = 10
```

And the code below is what I've tried in Python

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server=MyServer;database=MyDB;trusted_connection=true") 

cursor = conn.cursor()

SQL_command = """
                DBCC SHRINKFILE(comparables_v0_log, 100)

                BACKUP DATABASE MyDB
                TO  DISK = N'D:\MSSQL\BACKUP\MyDB_v0_noFSD.bak' WITH NOFORMAT
                ,   INIT
                ,   NAME = N'backup_MyDB_v0_noFSD.bak', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD
                ,   STATS = 10
              """

cursor.execute(SQL_command)
cursor.commit()
```

However, the above code generates an error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY007', '[HY007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver]Associated statement is not prepared (0) (SQLNumResultCols)')

May I know what is wrong with my Python code?

Comment: You've basically got two commands there with no separator between them. Either send each command separately, or put a separator (GO or ;) between them.Also, if pyOdbc has a executeNonQuery method that would be what you need - the query will return no rows and the error seems to suggest it's expecting some.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to recreate your specific error. According to the [Python Database API Spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), database connections must always be opened with auto-commit disabled. In other words, database operations must always occur in a transaction by default.

However, the T-SQL `DBCC SHRINKFILE` and `BACKUP` operations cannot be performed in a transaction, so we need to tell pyodbc that we want auto-commit enabled, which we can do with

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(my_connection_string, autocommit=True);
```

When I made that change the error went away, but the backup was still not happening. I'm not sure why that is, because I can do the same thing from other ODBC connections (e.g., from VBScript) and it worked there.

One workaround would be to create a stored procedure in the SQL Server database, e.g.,

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.doShrinkAndBackup
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DBCC SHRINKFILE(myDb_log, 100);

    BACKUP DATABASE myDb
    TO  DISK = N'C:\__tmp\myDb.bak' WITH NOFORMAT
    ,   INIT
    ,   NAME = N'myDb backup', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD
    ,   STATS = 10;
END
```

and then invoke the stored procedure from Python

```python
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(my_connection_string, autocommit=True);
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute('EXEC dbo.doShrinkAndBackup')
```

If you want to be able to tweak values at run-time then you can just add input parameters to the stored procedure.